# vb6 Crystal reports 9? how to simulate formatted string as separate records

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

Here's another one for ya.

I have a column in a database that consists of a formatted string containing titles and values associated to those titles.

such as: "Genre : Science Fiction   Style : Vintage   StuffTitle : StuffValue"

parsing the data is no problem.

I do a split on the 3 spaces separating the groups and then another split on the colon (:) to get each title and value.

The problem is I want crystal to see this as a record so I can apply formatting to the section containing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the different pieces to variables in one formula while taking care of your type casting, etc., and then create other formulas that return the value of each of these variables individually (one per piece of data you want to format individually). Then, drop them both in the same report section.

For example, if your parsing formula is {@parse}, and in it

```
...
numbervar sample := <some parsed value>
stringvar another := <some other value>
...
```

to return and format the first individually:

```
evaluateafter({@parse});
stringvar sample
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand, this appears as though it would only return the last parsed value.  If so, that wouldn't work.  Perhaps some more detail would help?

Comment: You'd make a formula for each parsed value. Together, the formulas would act the same as if they were separate columns of the same record and could be formatted individually.